# How to restore database files after update mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using laragon for my project, today (unfortunately) y has a problem with my SSD (C:) and I have to format all, my project was located is D:\ but MySql was not working, I updated from MySql 5.7.24 to 8.0.23

before doing that, I have saved database files and old MySQL files, now I don't have my database, my localhost is empty

I have files in .frm, .ibd from the database (my tables) and I have my old MySQL files (.MYI, .MYD, .frm, .ibd, etc)

How can I restore my database in mySQL-8?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. However, you can:

1. Back to MySQL 5.7.24
2. Dump your database to a sql file
3. Switch to MySQL 8
4. Restore from the dumped sql file

Note: If you have no purpose to upgrade, you should go with MySQL 5.7